# Trying to use TLS SMTP against Exim, getting Security Error back; what's wrong?

Tags: security, ssl, smtp, exim

OS: FreeBSD9 64 Bit

MTA: EXIM4 with TLS with Self Signed Certificate.

I am using

```
telnet myserver.com 25 
EHLO dummy@dummy.com
STARTTLS
```

It says

```
TLS go ahead
```

And then I issue

```
MSG FROM: me@me.com
```

It says


```
554 Security Error
```


*It first says tls is ok go ahead then produces error!!!!!*

Can someone figure out What is the problem. And/Or provide necessary solution.

If more information is required please let me know

I tested my tls here https://www.wormly.com/test_smtp_server, It produced:

```
Resolving hostname...
Connecting...
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 
SMTP -> ERROR: EHLO not accepted from server: 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 
SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server: 
Message sending failed.
```

Comment: run `openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect myserver.com:587` instead. It is supposed to handle TLS handshake internally. [s_client - SSL/TLS client program](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html)

Comment: @SparKotॐ, Thanks, It works. I still have problem but this one is over now. +1

Comment: @SparKotॐ You really should post that as a proper answer, so it can be voted on and accepted.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling you can add the above command to supplement your well explained answer.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the response to `STARTTLS` simply indicates that you should go ahead and do TLS negotiation; it does *not* mean that the link is now covered by TLS. TLS negotiation is the process of the two systems involved agreeing on keys, exchanging certificates, etc., all in the name of establishing a trusted, encrypted channel between the two systems.

Quoting [RFC 2487](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2487.txt) (SMTP Service Extension for Secure SMTP over TLS), section 5 `The STARTTLS Command`:

```
After receiving a 220 response to a STARTTLS command, the client
SHOULD start the TLS negotiation before giving any other SMTP
commands.
```

Also see section 6 `Usage Example` in the same RFC. Note that it specifically elides the actual TLS negotiation process.

When the server expects you to start negotiating TLS, and you instead give a SMTP (or not even SMTP) command, that is extremely likely to be an error. I'm not familiar with the TLS negotiation process internals but the odds that either `MSG FROM:` or `MAIL FROM:` forms valid TLS negotiation initiation stanzas would appear to me to be incredibly tiny. The SMTP server, in this case, is well within its rights to refuse your failed attempt at TLS negotiation; hence the error you receive back.

*In addition to that*, there are two problems with your `MSG FROM: me@me.com` immediately following the `STARTTLS`:

1. There is no `MSG FROM` command in SMTP. The proper syntax is `MAIL FROM:<me@me.com>`
2. The SMTP session is reset to the initial state when the TLS negotiation completes (see RFC 2487 section 5.2), so you must restart by first giving a `EHLO` or possibly `HELO`

If you want to connect to a SMTP server that requires STARTTLS, then you can use [OpenSSL's SSL/TLS client](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html) for that purpose rather than telnet. That will be something along the lines of `openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect smtp.example.com:587` for SMTP STARTTLS. Once the connection has been established you can simply use the then properly set up SMTP connection (start at the `EHLO`).

Comment: Thank you.

I now did

`STARTTLS->EHLO DUMMY@DUMMY.COM->MAIL FROM:ME@ME.COM`

BUT YET SAME ERROR.

Comment: @Nishan Please read my answer again. `EHLO DUMMY@DUMMY.COM` CRLF `MAIL FROM:ME@ME.COM` CRLF is almost certainly **not a valid TLS negotiation**.

Comment: I am sorry. Can you please tell me what you mean by **VALID TLS NEGOTIATION**. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: @Nishan Not in comments. See my edits.

Comment: @Downvoter a comment explaining what might be wrong with the answer would be appreciated, so I can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send an `ALRM` signal to it after the `TLS go ahead`,

```
killall -ALRM gnutls-cli
```

You can do this via another terminal or by hitting `Crtl-Z` to background the current process, doing the `killall` command, then typing `fg` to return to the `SMTP` session.